# Mongo: Isit possible to conditionally $lookup? Or somehow terminate a lookup faster?

Tags: mongodb, lookup

Because of the way some legacy data is structured it looks like that

- `Child (id, parentId, parentType)` can be associated with 3 types of parents each in its own collection
- Lets call the parent collections `ParentType1, ParentType2, ParentType3`

Currently, in some cases, I need to join these collections, currently, I lookup 3 separate collections to get the info I need, but its really slow

Each lookup looks like:

```
{
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "ParentType{*}",
            "as": "parentType{*}",
            "let": {
                "parentId": "$parentId",
            },
            "pipeline": [
                {
                    "$match": {
                        "$and": [
                            {
                                "$expr": {
                                    "$eq": [
                                        "$_id",
                                        "$$parentId"
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "$limit": 1
                }
            ]
        }
    },
```

The observation is even if the child is not of the correct parent type, alot of time is taken to do the lookup only to find nothing, wonder if theres a better way to do this?

Just some things I considered:

- Embed or not? But for this, if embedded, the performance to write to all child records might be painful to manage. But maybe will explore this option if nothing else can be done
- Merge all the parent collections into 1 to avoid 3 separate lookups (not sure if it will help much though)

Comment: Do you have an index on `parentId`? Then the index should be used, otherwise try `{ $lookup: { from: "ParentType{*}", localField: "parentId", foreignField: "_id", as: "parentType{*}" } }`.

Comment: Maybe it is an option to update your legacy data to new structure. Should be a one-time job only.

Comment: Yes theres an index. But according to explain, seems like the bulk of the time is still in the lookups, and I suspect its not done in parallel either